# Get Narrow Type from Object of Methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, narrowing

I want to get a Narrowing type like this:

```
type Expected = {
    method: 'firstNamespace/firstMethod'
    payload: [string]
} | {
    method: 'firstNamespace/secondMethod'
    payload: [number, number]
} | {
    method: 'secondNamespace/firstMethod'
    payload: [number]
}
```

From an object of methods like this:

```
const Methods = {
    firstNamespace: {
        firstMethod: (p: string) => {},
        secondMethod: (p: number, k: number) => {}
    },
    secondNamespace: {
        firstMethod: (p: number) => {}
    }
}
```

I have tried various things but I think there is something I am misunderstanding in TypeScript.

I've been working with TypeScript almost a year and anything that exceeds basic types seems out of my reach...

Comment: Have you trully gone through: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html
There is plenty.

Comment: Are you looking to handle arbitrarily nested `Methods`-like structures?  Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mAVO8W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example with some failing use cases.

Comment: It's just what I needed, thank you very much @jcalz !

I'm going to do my best to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in TypeScript via [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to drill down into the nested properties of `Methods`, and [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to concatenate the method names together at the type level.

Let's call the type function you are looking for as `MethodsToExpected<T>`, which takes an object type `T` and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types whose `method` property is a `"/"`-delimited path to each method name and whose `payload` property is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the corresponding method's parameter types.  Then we can define `MethodsToExpected<T>` recursively in terms of itself like this:

```
type MethodsToExpected<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
    T[K] extends (...args: infer P) => any ? { method: K, payload: P } :
    MethodsToExpected<T[K]> extends infer X ? (
        X extends { method: infer M, payload: infer P } ? (
            { method: `${Extract<K, string>}/${Extract<M, string>}`; payload: P }
        ) : never
    ) : never
}[keyof T]
```

The construction `{[K in keyof T]-?: XXX}[keyof T]`, which immediately [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with its keys, producing a union of all the `XXX` types.

For each property key `K` from `T`, we check the property type `T[K]`.  If it's a function type, then we grab its list of parameter list and immediately return `{method: K, payload: P}`.  Otherwise we apply `MethodsToExpected<T[K]>` to the property and inspect it.

(Aside: I'm using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to "copy" `MethodsToExpected<T[K]>` into a new type parameter `X`, which I then use as the checked type in a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so that any unions in `X` are distributed to the final union.  If you just used `MethodsToExpected<T[K]> extends {method: infer M, payload: infer P}` instead of the intermediate `X`, it would produce things like `{method: "a/b" | "a/c", payload: [string] | [number]}` instead of the desired `{method: "a/b", payload: [string]} | {method: "a/c", payload: [number]}`.)

For each union element of `MethodsToExpected<T[K]>`, we pull out the `method` type `M` and the `payload` type `P`, and build a new `method`/`payload` pair.  The `payload` type doesn't change and is just `P`, but we prepend the current key `K` and a slash `"/"` to the `M` with a template literal type.  The compiler can't be sure that `K` and `M` are both `string` types so it doesn't want to let you write `` `${K}/${M}` `` directly.  Instead we use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to convince the compiler that we will only be concatenating `string`s.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
type Expected = MethodsToExpected<typeof Methods>;
/* type Expected = {
    method: "firstNamespace/firstMethod";
    payload: [p: string];
} | {
    method: "firstNamespace/secondMethod";
    payload: [p: number, k: number];
} | {
    method: "secondNamespace/firstMethod";
    payload: [p: number];
} */
```

Looks good.  Just to be sure that it drills down into nested subproperties, let's try a different one:

```
type Nested = MethodsToExpected<{ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: (f: string) => number } } } } }>;
/* type Nested = {
    method: "a/b/c/d/e";
    payload: [f: string];
} */
```

Also good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&noErrorTruncation=true#code/PQKgLgngDgpgBAUQB6wMZhgEzgXjgbwCgBIAWxjAAsB7TALjgHIAzASwCcBnMAOQENynKH1QxgbLmACyFGpkYlhEADbU+9OAG1u7VgDsA5gF1CAXzgAfAiXJVaDFh279Bw0cE4xU1PZhl35RT4VNQ1NPQBXUgAjGHYAGjhImLiTcysiMll7Jk9vXxcYIRExCW5-OQViJVV1BnCo2PY0kGBCdvzuOAraTlxrYjLeASK3GAZMwadpbI0ACigGHX0DAEpcAD4COFN4kmI8nz9ZhgWGZKbEgGtzxrj1nC38HZJdkkOCkeLRCf2hnvmiySd3YDyeL2IpjM7UgsG6s04ABVqMg0BhMAAeRFbPDPTQAaTg+jgVxgEGozDgiKMAFoAPx0EiIglGOAwJAYXx9OYAOj5fHYBk4DH0zDicAACmC4Hw9BA4HTtrY5Ax8YkaqEGBKdnBGcQAUiUSgvOisSytuzOZg+qLxQANBVwOb7B2WmBcpUnIl6MXsbrq4K1DS2v3a8yK53EKPPZU5AAGABJ8MgwOwRGAMWq4MtDBtTMAkym0+gMVJEjmDHm4wBuOAauqSiHEdbnGAANziJBbSXbndMmlJ5Mp1Jh0HgqJNWH6BuRE-QWAxsJgFPhAU4G2rhFAcCXiGN8+wuJsXoARENCt9StMASfN9VA5qtECK0ZN+kBrGNGfphexh4vEcN53vWYRAhccTXLcKTNG+lgfqeHyYL+JTiNesy3kEIQNpoYEgq+ZhwK0o5wjwRTotOCKzvuprPHwExwNE9GoPRGjPOMTrMEsqYrNK4F+uYAk6qYG5biAO5jnApHcFOR5ZAEDAnnwwDRMAqDAJgwAwBh95YWEnHZtxhj4eYrRAA)

Comment: This is awesome.